# How to modify the content of an array according to its content ordering efficiently?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question regarding array. For example, if I know the size of the array will be 5, and my programme read in

```
[9993, 1000, 9992, 3, 872]
```

into the array, how can I edit the content of the array efficiently such that it becomes

```
[5, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

I can only implement a double for-loop which runs at O(n^2). I hope to find a better algorithm   for it.

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to construct the ordering?  You can do that in `O(n log n)` time and `O(n)` space by constructing an auxiliary array containing integers `1...n`, sorting the auxiliary array using a comparator that refers to the elements of the original array, and then copying the auxiliary array into the original.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, but I don't quite understand how the referencing back to the original elements can be implemented using a comparator.

Could you elaborate more?

Comment: `if (origArray[auxArray[i]-1] < origArray[auxArray[j]-1]) { ... } /* etc. */`.  Notice the `-1` since your result is 1-based, not 0-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to have a class like this:

```
class Tuple implements Comparable<Tuple> {
    int value;  // value
    int pos;    // position in array

    public Tuple(int value, int pos) {
        this.value = value;
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tuple other) {  // sort based on values
        return Integer.compare(value, other.value);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Tuple[] tups = new Tuple[array.length];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    tups[i] = new Tuple(array[i], i);

Arrays.sort(tups);

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = tups[i].pos + 1;
```

This is an O(n log n) process, owing to the array sorting.

Comment: Hi Arshajii, your algorithm will return [4, 5, 2, 3, 1] instead.

Comment: @boxme See the edit, I just did `tups[i].pos + 1` on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you must use one sort of sorting algorithm so therefore the best runtime you will be able to get is O(n logn). There are plenty of sorting algorithms you can find online if you search for them. The fastest ones I'd recommend learning for beginners are Quicksort, Mergesort and Heapsort.